# How to add extra classes to Wordpress's body element?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In the default Wordpress template, there is this in `header.php`.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This echos some useful hooks for CSS and JavaScript. Some example output is

```
<body class="page page-id-45 page-template page-template-gallery-php">
```

Is it possible, within the `header.php` even, to add my own classes in addition to what is there?

Specifically, I'd like to do a quick `strstr` on `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and add a class if the device is an *iDevice*.

I figure I could do it with JavaScript, but still being able to know how to add my own classes would be useful nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just pass the extra class-name as a parameter, i.e.

```
<body <?php body_class('myclassname'); ?>>
```

...which seems to be [confirmed here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/body_class).